# Using tsboot to obtain confidence interval from a regression with lags

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to do a bootstrap of regression coefficient in a return model that includes two lags.
I have snp_ret vector with returns obtained from quantmod. The data looks like this:

```
head(snp_ret)
                  ret
1998-10-13 -0.2920975
1998-10-14  1.0728374
1998-10-15  4.0882022
1998-10-16  0.8489058
1998-10-19  0.5635226
1998-10-20  0.1448549
```

Obtaining bootstrap for coefficients should be simple:

```
getC=function(myData){
  return(coef(lm(formula = dyn(ret ~ lag(ret, c(-1,-9))), data=myData) ))
}

tsboot(snp_ret, getC, R = 100, l = 18, sim = "fixed")
```

The following error appears:

> **Error in merge.zoo(ret, lag(ret, c(-1, -9)), retclass = "list", all
>   = TRUE) :    series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series**

I suspect that it has to do with the fact that regression has two lags, but do not know how to proceed.

If possible, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I found a workaround, so maybe this will be interesting to somebody else... Using arima function instead of lag operators helped.

```
getC <- function(myData) { 
  reg <- suppressWarnings(arima(myData, order = c(9, 0, 0), fixed = c(NA, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,NA)))
  return((coef(reg)[c(1,9,10)]))
```

Note that arima has a weird way of selecting lags - you have to force to zero coefficients on lags that you don't want to include